# CSS Image url are not rendring correctly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Hello guys thanx in advance...
I created HTML and CSS - all images rendering correctly in both FF & chrome
But Some issue with IE

When I'm trying to use `<img src="same_path_as_per_css"/>` then it works fine with IE

But when I use `background: url("same_path_as_per_html");`

not working in IE

here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/KKWLS/2/

Any ideas!!

Comment: all version including 10.0, Specially #banner {BG}

Comment: The path should relative to the stylesheet, not the page using the stylesheet. JSFiddle can't really demonstrate this because of lack of folders.

Comment: @Diodes-"The path should relative to the stylesheet"
...But if there is path issue then- how can images are working fine  FF & chrome? could u please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the quotes out/replacing with straight/curly quotes.

```
background:url(../images/menubar.jpg);
```

Also the file should be relative to the CSS file and not the HTML file.

Also there should not be any space between url and ()